# List of functions used in a Matlab script

Tags: matlab, function, editor

Is it possible to obtain a list of the user-supplied functions (functions which are not Matlab toolbox functions) called by a  Matlab script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the MATLAB Current Folder window, navigate to the folder containing your script. Right-click on the background of the window, and select Reports->Dependency Report. You should get a nice report detailing the dependencies of all the files in that folder.

You can achieve roughly the same result programmatically with the command `depfun`, or since version 2014a, `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`.

Comment: This produces exactly what I was looking for, thanks